# How to use temporary table or view in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, view, mapping, temp-tables

I would like to use temporary table in my HQL query, can I do it?

P.S. I do know there are some hacks with creating your own dialect, but I don't want to do that, but I can create view for that table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hiii,

There is no difference between a view and a base table for a Hibernate mapping. This is transparent at the database level, although some DBMS do not support views properly, especially with updates.

And Avoid temporary tables use views if possible.

Comment: I would like to avoid temporary tables, but I have no choice here. its good to know that I can map view as table, thx.